# Evaluate $\int^{2}_{0}f(x)dx$

Tags: proof-verification, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)=f(-x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. If $\int^{3}_{-3}f(x)dx=0$ and $\int^{3}_{-2}f(x)dx=5$, then $\int^{2}_{0}f(x)dx=...$

First I tried this:

$\begin{aligned}
\int^{3}_{-3}f(x)dx&=2\int^{3}_{0}f(x)dx\\
\int^{3}_{0}f(x)dx&=0\\\\
\int^{3}_{-2}f(x)dx&=\int^{0}_{-2}f(x)dx+\int^{3}_{0}f(x)dx\\
&=\int^{0}_{-2}f(x)dx
\end{aligned}$

Let $u=-x$, then $du=-dx$.

$\begin{aligned}
-\int^{0}_{2}f(x)dx&=\int^{2}_{0}f(x)dx\\
&=5
\end{aligned}$

Therefore:
$\begin{aligned}
\int^{2}_{0}f(x)dx&=5
\end{aligned}$

But I didn't feel it's the right method. From the first hypothesis, we know that $f(x)$ is an even function. To satisfy $\int^{3}_{-3}f(x)dx=0$ then $f(x)$ should be $f(x)=0$. But if I assume $f(x)=0$ then it won't satisfy $\int^{3}_{-2}f(x)dx=5$. My questions are:

1. Are there other even function that satisfy $\int^{3}_{-3}f(x)dx=0$ other than $f(x)=0$? As far as I know it's only applied at odd function.
2. If not can I use the first method or there's another method to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-3}^3\cos\frac{\pi x}{3}dx=0$$

Comment: Satisfying all of OP's restrictions is $$ f(x) = \frac{10\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\cos\frac{\pi x}{3} .$$

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct. There are lots of  non-zero  even functions with $\int_{-3}^{3} f(x)dx=0$. For example we may have $f(x)=\cos(\pi x)$ 0n $(0,3)$.

Comment: Notice the requirement that $f(x)=f(-x),\,\forall x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple function satisfying your condition:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & |x|>3 \\
\frac{5}{2} & -2 \leq x \leq 2 \\
-5 & -3 \leq x < -2  \mbox{ and } 2 <x \leq 3
\end{cases}$$